# Is there any way to prevent sectors from building on a specific tile of a planet?

Tags: stellaris

One of the colonized planets in my empire has the Alien Pets resource. Unfortunately, despite having the "Respect Tile Resources" button checked, when I put that system under sector control, the sector builds over it (Possibly because the tile also has 6 Society, so it builds a Science Lab). And I would ***really*** like to have that resource, because a functioning Xeno Zoo would really help pacify the angry planet of xenophobic isolationists I recently conquered.

Building *anything* over that tile (even a Xeno Zoo that uses the resource) suppresses the collection of Alien pets. So how can I prevent a sector from suppressing the collection of rare resources like Alien Pets? I already have a number of planets that I don't want to place under sector control due to their strategic importance, and this sector puts me over my limit.

Comment: Patch 1.10 will be changing this functionality; buildings will no longer supress strategic resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way you can do this besides controlling the planet yourself. Sectors are completely autonomous and if you already checked "Respect Tile Resoruces" there is no further instruction you can give.
The sector AI most likely considers 6 society research worth more than an alien pet (I would as well)

Options you have:

1. Take the pet planet under direct control until the situation on the xenophobic world stabilized and add one of your core planets to a sector for the duration
2. Just deal with the revolts by reducing faction support and doing integration campaigns.
3. put the xenophobic planet in a sector and let it worry about it
4. enslave the xenophobic pop.

Comment: Part of the problem is that the system in question has multiple colonies, so that would impact my core planets count by more than a bit. I've already maxed out the integration campaigns, and all I have left are suppress media and bribe leaders. Somewhat hilariously, by grouping them in with a nearby sector, the xenophobes just shift their goal-posts; independence for the *whole* sector! Fortunately they are slowly losing support as my empire's negative ethical divergence slowly realigns them into something less xenophoby. Would still be nice to have some alien pets for that Xeno Zoo, though.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.8, players can direct what a planet in a sector builds, if they so wish. Additionally, the AI is a little smarter when it comes to deciding what to build in regards to respecting resources, although it still sometimes needs a little help. But that's OK, because you can order that planet to build a building, build a starport, build a starport module, build a ship, or move population around. Just be aware that ordering a planet in a sector to build something will subtract the resources from your resource pool and not the sector's.